# Assigning password to shell prompt after .sh is triggered

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I have sample .sh file which i will have to trigger upon deployment. .sh will switch from root user to a specific user.

Assuming my original .sh file consist of

```
# this will switch from root and login as user1
pbrun -u user1 dap
```

when i run my shell script as `sh /path/test.sh` , terminal will prompt me

```
Please Enter Password for user1:

Password:
```

after i keyed in the password,it will next prompt me

```
Reason(Please Input VT information here):
```

i am trying to automate this process without the need to manually key in the password. The ideal approach and for testing purposes only, is to insert the password inside .sh script.
I have tried with below script , it did not fail but it still prompt for password and reason

```
pbrun -u user1 dap
PASS="helloworld"
read -p "Password: " mypassword
echo ""
[ "$mypassword" == "$PASS" ] ; then
echo "Password Accepted"
failed=$(( $failed + 3 )) ; then
echo "Incorrect Password"
```

The logic i have in mind is

```
pbrun -u user1 dap
#if system prompt for password, insert "helloworld"
#if user prompt for reasons, insert "testing"
```

When i ran test.sh file. it should not prompt me for any password or reasons as this is already declared in .sh file itself. is approach this possible?

Comment: What is pbrun and why are you running it before everything else? If you want to interact with that program, you'll need a way to hook into it (like [expect](https://core.tcl.tk/expect/)). Otherwise, you'll need to figure out how to feed it data non-interactively, which would happen _before_ invoking it.

Comment: If you know that all prompts in the script are simply processed by `read` commands, and find `expect` too complicated, you could also feed them via standard input, since you know the order of the prompts.

Comment: is it possible to write this in python instead ? using expect will require additional library.